# ¿hay alguna manera de aumentar la etiqueta h1 con php?

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

verán estoy apenas aprendiendo php en la universidad y llevo todo el día tratando de hacer este ejercicio y por más que lo intento no encuentro un método para poder aumentar la etiqueta como se pide, si alguien me pudiera orientar gracias :3

```
<form name = "Form" method = "post">
<input type="text" name = "Texto">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<br>
<?php

 $Texto = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Texto');
 
 function Repeticion($Texto){
 for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
 //aqui deberia concatenarse
 }
 ?>
```

el texto lo estaba tratando de recibir así en un input pero no creo que haya problemas a la hora de aplicar el for

Comment: Es muy fácil lo que te están pidiendo, muestra lo que has intentado pulsando en [edit] y podremos ayudarte sin duda.

Answer (score -1):

Ayudaría mucho que editaras la pregunta con más información de lo que has intentado hasta ahora o cómo es que obtienes el texto que hay que encerrar en etiquetas H.

De cualquier forma, el programa puede ser algo muy parecido a esto:

```
$texto="hola";
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    print("<h$i>$texto</h$i>");
}
```

La solución está en:

- los parámetros del ciclo for `for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++)`
- la sustitución de variables en el texto `"<h$i>$texto<h$i>"`

Sigue con el esfuerzo y recuerda que siempre puedes consultar el manual de php para ayudarte a recordar: https://www.php.net/manual/es/index.php

Comment: Aunque se agradece la ayuda, procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad o en donde no se haya demostrado esfuerzo por parte del autor. Lee [answer].